# display the textviews referenced in XML in database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have checked all the answers about pre-populating database, however none of them show how to insert REFERENCED TEXT VIEWS in database or manually enter the exercise names in onCreate() of SQLiteOpenHelper so that the textview appear on the opening of the database. I came across one where ContentValues was used in onCreate(), but that didn't work for me. Additionally, I also tried to display the exercise name manually in onCreate(see code in DatabaseManager below) but no luck.

Basically, I have 3 columns in my database , KEY_ROWID, KEY_EXERCISENAME and KEY_DURATION where ROWID Is auto increment, KEY_DURATION is editText for different exercises and KEY_EXERCISENAME is where I want to display all the names of the exercise contained in my XML layout(weekone.xml). So, when the user views the database, all the exercise names are already displayed  under KEY_EXERCISENAME and all he has to enter the particular value of those exercise in their respective edit boxes.

weekone.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!--
    Begin Relative Layout
    -->
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/originallayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:background="@drawable/appbackground">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:background="#00141c"
        android:fontFamily="Hobo Std"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/start"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backarrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/about_title"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/week4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingTop="400dp"
            android:src="@drawable/weekfour" />



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/week3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/week4"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingTop="400dp"
            android:src="@drawable/weekthree" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/week2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/week3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingTop="400dp"
            android:src="@drawable/weektwo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/week1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/week2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingTop="400dp"
            android:src="@drawable/weekone" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#00000000"

        android:paddingTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/weekone">

        <!--     Line seperator     -->

        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:background="#00141c"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/week1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/week1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#00141c"/>


                <!-- Begin Scrollable Linear Layout -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="325dp" >

       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true">     

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/treadmillimage"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/treadmill" />

                <!--     Line seperator     -->

        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:background="#00141c"/>


                <!--    End Relative Layout   -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/durOnTreadmill"
            android:layout_width="129dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:hint="hh:mm:ss" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true">


        <TextView                               
            android:id="@+id/treadmilltext"     <----- name of exercise machine in textview
            android:layout_width="91dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/treadmill"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="91dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
            android:text="@string/dur"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    <!--        Begin Relative Layou        -->

        <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stepperimage"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/stepper" />

            <!--     Line seperator     -->

        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:background="#00141c"/>


             <!--   End Relative Layout  -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/durOnStepper"
            android:layout_width="129dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="hh:mm:ss" />

            <requestFocus />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/steppertext"       <------ name of exercise machine in textView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="@string/stepper"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="91dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
            android:text="@string/dur"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    <!--    Begin Relative Layout    -->

        <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stationaryrowing"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/stationaryrowing" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/durOnStationaryRowing"
            android:layout_width="129dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" 
            android:hint="hh:mm:ss"/>

        <!--     Line seperator     -->

        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:background="#00141c"/>


    <!--
    End Relative Layout
    -->
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stationaryrowingtext"      <------ name of exercise machine in textView
            android:layout_width="108dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="@string/stationaryrowing"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="91dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
            android:text="@string/dur"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

         <!--   Begin Relative Layout   -->
         <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/exercisebikeimage"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/excerisebike"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/durOnExerciseBike"
            android:layout_width="129dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" 
            android:hint="hh:mm:ss"/>

            <!--     Line seperator     -->

        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:background="#00141c"/>

        <!--    End Relative Layout  -->

        </RelativeLayout>

         <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true">

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/excerisebiketext"      <------ name of exercise machine in textView
            android:layout_width="91dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="@string/exercisebike"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="91dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
            android:text="@string/dur"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

         </RelativeLayout>

        <!--    Begin Relative Layout   -->

           <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:scrollHorizontally="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ellipticaltrainerimage"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ellipticaltrainer"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/durOnellipticaltrainer"
            android:layout_width="129dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" 
            android:hint="hh:mm:ss"/>

            <!--     Line seperator     -->

        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:background="#00141c"/>

        <!--        End Relative Layout      -->

    </RelativeLayout>

           <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:scrollHorizontally="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ellipticaltrainertext"     <------ name of exercise machine in textView
                android:layout_width="91dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="@string/ellipticaltrainer"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/duration"
                android:layout_width="91dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
                android:text="@string/dur"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

           <Button 
               android:id = "@+id/saveButton"
               android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
               android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
               android:text = "@string/save"/>

           <Button 
               android:id = "@+id/viewButton"
               android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
               android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
               android:text = "@string/view"/>

        </LinearLayout>

       <!--     End ScrollView   -->

      </ScrollView>

        <!--        End Linear Layout        -->

    </LinearLayout>     

        <!--        End Linear Layout       -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

DatabaseManager.java

```
package com.example.draft;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseManager 
{

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_EXERCISENAME = "exercisename";
public static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "weekOne";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public DbHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL
        ("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_EXERCISENAME + " EXERCISEBIKE, " +     <----------Exercise name entered manually
            KEY_DURATION + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );



    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public DatabaseManager(Context c)
{
    ourContext = c; 
}

public DatabaseManager open() 
{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;    
}

public void close()
{
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String treadmillTimings) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_DURATION, treadmillTimings);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null,cv);

}

public String getData() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_EXERCISENAME, KEY_DURATION};
    Cursor cur = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iExerciseName = cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXERCISENAME);
    int iDuration = cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_DURATION);

    for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext())
    {
        result = result + cur.getString(iRow) + "        " + cur.getString(iExerciseName) + "    " + cur.getString(iDuration) + "\n";
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

WeekOne.java (class in which all the textView are referenced

```
//referencing textViews 

    treadmillText = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.treadmilltext);
    stepperText = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.steppertext);
    ellipticalTrainerText = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.ellipticaltrainertext);
    stationaryRowingText = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.stationaryrowingtext);
    exerciseBikeText = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.excerisebiketext);
```

Is it even possible what I am trying to do

Thanks :)

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you want to set the text from the `KEY_EXERCISENAME` columns in those `TextViews`?

Comment: I want to set the textviews in the column of KEY_EXERCISENAME (e.g KEY_EXERCISENAME contains treadmillText, stepperText, exerciseBikeText stationaryRowingText and ellipticalTrainerText) hope you can understand. if not pleese tell me

Answer (score 0):

Manage to solve it ! :D, i wasn't assingning`KEY_EXERCISENAME` to any name of the exercise. So, after all the research and not giving up at all inserted `'cv.put(KEY_EXERCISENAME, "Treadmill")` in `createEntry()` and worked like a pro

Thanks for all your replied and support :)